# Google Cloud PubSub Error: Deadline Exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I have a simple service that publishes messages to a PubSub topic and occasionally get a "Deadline Exceeded" error message:

> GaxError(RPC failed, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated
>   with (StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, Deadline Exceeded)>)

Python code:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
pubsub_client = pubsub.Client()
topic = pubsub_client.topic("pubsub-topic")
data = data.encode('utf-8')
message_id = topic.publish(data)
```

It posts a few messages a second, from a Flask web app, and maybe one in a few hundred fail with that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was creating too many PubSub clients!

I moved this part outside the function / route so that the topic and client are global variables and aren't initialized with each call:

```
pubsub_client = pubsub.Client()
topic = pubsub_client.topic("pubsub-topic")
```

(Right after instantiating Flask):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Comment: What is Flask? I am also facing same issue